# SASS respect order of mixin

Tags: css, sass

How can I get SASS to respect the order of the mixin:

## SASS input:

```
@mixin containerMargins {
  margin: 4rem 10vw;


    @media only screen and (min-width: 768) {
        margin: 7rem 10vw;
    };

    @media only screen and (min-width: 1024) {
        margin: 7rem 20vw;
    };
}

.myContainer {
  @include containerMargins;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

## SASS output:

```
.myContainer {
  margin: 4rem 10vw;
  margin-top: 0;  /* I want this to be at the bottom */
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768) {
  .myContainer {
    margin: 7rem 10vw;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024) {
  .myContainer {
    margin: 7rem 20vw;
  }
}
```

## Desired output:

```
.myContainer {
  margin: 4rem 10vw;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768) {
  .myContainer {
    margin: 7rem 10vw;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024) {
  .myContainer {
    margin: 7rem 20vw;
  };
}
.myContainer {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

How can I make the margin-top come last? i.e. everything in the mixin (including the @media queries) should come before margin-top. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean `at the bottom`? If you look at your output, the `media` queries are OUTSIDE of your class. Also, you need to add `px` to your `min-width` sizes, or your media queries won't do anything anyway.

Comment: @disinfor Updated the question with what I want, hopefully it's more clear.

Comment: Your output want is invalid. Look at where the `margin-top: 0` is. It's outside off all selectors. Do you want the `margin-top: 0` inside the `media` query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create parameters for your mixin so you can pass in a value for the `margin-top` property:

```
@mixin containerMargins( $sm:'', $md:'', $lg:'' ) {
  margin: 4rem 10vw;
  margin-top: #{$sm};


    @media only screen and (min-width: 768) {
        margin: 7rem 10vw;
        margin-top: #{$md};
    };

    @media only screen and (min-width: 1024) {
        margin: 7rem 20vw;
        margin-top: #{$lg};
    };
}

.myContainer {
  @include containerMargins('','','0');
}
```

This outputs:

```
.myContainer {
  margin: 4rem 10vw;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768) {
  .myContainer {
    margin: 7rem 10vw;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024) {
  .myContainer {
    margin: 7rem 20vw;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

If you leave the `@include containerMargins();` parameters empty, it outputs this CSS:

```
.myContainer {
  margin: 4rem 10vw;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768) {
  .myContainer {
    margin: 7rem 10vw;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024) {
  .myContainer {
    margin: 7rem 20vw;
  }
}
```

That will then not affect the `margin-top` property.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you. Using inherit did indeed break my css.

Comment: Awesome! Yeah, I removed it. I forgot that `inherit` takes the style from the parent. The updated answer removes the property completely if there isn't a value explicitly passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest possible way I would go is:

```
.myContainer { 
    @include containerMargins;
}
.myContainer {margin-top: 0; }
```

Comment: This does indeed work. I wonder if there is a less hacky answer though.

Answer (score 0):

seems like your doubling the margin top here in a shorthand:

margin: 4rem //-> Top +bottom  10vw // left + right-> ;

and then adding "margin-top: 0;

Try something like this:

```css
@mixin containerMargins {

    @media only screen and (min-width: 768) {
        margin: 7rem 10vw;
    };

    @media only screen and (min-width: 1024) {
        margin: 7rem 20vw;
    };
}

.myContainer {
  @include containerMargins;
  margin-top: 0;
}

OR


@mixin containerMargins {
  margin: 4rem 10vw;

    @media only screen and (min-width: 768) {
        margin: 7rem 10vw;
    };

    @media only screen and (min-width: 1024) {
        margin: 7rem 20vw;
    };
}

.myContainer {
  @include containerMargins;
}
```

Depending on your desired output.